# How to customize email link in salesforce?

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-component, custom-field, inline-visualforce

How to customize or override an email field link (in a standard page layout) to make an ajax call to an url instead of opening a "mailto:xxx@yyy.com" link which is the standard functionality in salesforce lead object?